# Parse Multiple XML files with jQuery and display as hierarchical tree

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, treeview

New to jquery and ajax and I'm trying to create an html page which will display information from two xml files in a hierarchical tree view. Categories.xml will define the categories of all the various products and products.xml will contain all of the individual product data. 'Products.xml' shares a foreign key called 'categoryID' with 'categories.xml'. At this stage, I can't get any of the XML data to load to the page at all, let alone get a hierarchical tree view. I've searched around for hours for an answer but I can't seem to find anything about loading the two xml files and populating the tree with information from both files. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadBtn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "products.xml",
            datatype: "xml",
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(xml) {
                console.log('AJAX Request successful.');

                var productTable= '';
                productTable += '<table id="productTable" cellspacing="2" border="0">' ;

                productTable += '<thead><td>Product ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Quantity Per Unit</td><td>Unit Price</td></thead>';

                $(xml).find('product').each(function(){
                    productTable += '<tr>';
                    productTable += '<td>';
                    productTable += $(this).find('ProductId').text();
                    productTable += '</td>';

                    productTable += '<td>';
                    productTable += $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                    productTable += '</td>';

                    productTable += '<td>';
                    productTable += $(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
                    productTable += '</td>';

                    productTable += '<td>';
                    productTable += $(this).find('UnitPrice').text();
                    productTable += '</td>';

                    productTable += '</tr>';
                });
                productTable += '</table>';
                $("#products").append(productTable);

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<title>Products</title>
</head>

<body>
Click to Load:
<input type="button" id="loadBtn" value="Products"/>
<br/><br/>
<div id=products></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and for my XML files (products)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductsRoot>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>18</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chang</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>24 - 12 oz bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>19</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>3</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Aniseed Syrup</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 - 550 ml bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
</ProductsRoot>
```

and XML for categories

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CategoriesRoot>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName>
        <Description>Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Condiments</CategoryName>
        <Description>Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Confections</CategoryName>
        <Description>Desserts, candies, sweetbreads</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>4</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Dairy Products</CategoryName>
        <Description>Cheeses</Description>
    </Categories>
</Categories Root>
```

I've appended the xml to save on space but thats the general idea...

Can anyone be of any assistance with helping me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the code? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I"m not getting any errors. It just prints out the table headings over and over again without actually populating it with any data. Thats where I got stuck.

Comment: Look at `Products` in xml vs `products` in code. Try making cases match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why `.find();` is not working for you but, alternatively, you could just use `getElementsByTagName()` to get those values on the xml. Consider this example:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Quantity Per Unit</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="values">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'products.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(response) {
            var values = response.getElementsByTagName('Products');
            $.each(values, function(index, element){
                var product_id = element.getElementsByTagName('ProductID')[0].innerHTML;
                var product_name = element.getElementsByTagName('ProductName')[0].innerHTML;
                var category_id = element.getElementsByTagName('CategoryID')[0].innerHTML;
                var quantity = element.getElementsByTagName('QuantityPerUnit')[0].innerHTML;
                var unit_price = element.getElementsByTagName('UnitPrice')[0].innerHTML;

                var table_data = '<tr>';
                table_data += '<td>'+product_id+'</td>';
                table_data += '<td>'+product_name+'</td>';
                table_data += '<td>'+category_id+'</td>';
                table_data += '<td>'+quantity+'</td>';
                table_data += '<td>'+unit_price+'</td>';
                table_data += '</tr>';

                $('#values').append(table_data);
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried your solution but for some reason using that script only gives fills the table with 'undefined' values...

Comment: @p.rock i dont know why its not working in your copy, you can check it on the browsers console for errors, in my particular example, products.xml is in the same directory as the file thats processing it.

Comment: Cheers, I ran it in another browser and it populated the table... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There it goes a simple example in how to combine multiple XML data using two ajax calls. This should give put you in the right track ;)
https://gist.github.com/marcoramires/a88c85cea3690c7cbb73

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu_wrapper').append('<ul></ul>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Categories.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Fetching categories...');
                $(data).find('Categories').each(function () {
                    if($(this).children().length)
                    {
                        var categoryID = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                        var categoryName = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();
                        var description = $(this).find('Description').text();

                        var html = '<a href="#'+ categoryName +'" title="' + description + '">' + categoryName + '</a>';
                        $('<li id="' + categoryID + '"></li>').html(html).appendTo('#menu_wrapper ul');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('An error occurred while processing Categories XML file.');
                //alert('An error occurred while processing Categories XML file.');
            }
        }).done(function(){
            console.log('... done.');
            console.log('Fetching products...');
            getProducts();
        });

        var getProducts = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Products.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find('Products').each(function () {
                        if($(this).children().length)
                        {
                            var productID = $(this).find('ProductID').text();
                            var productName = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                            var categoryID = $(this).find('CategoryID').text();
                            var qtyPerUnity = $(this).find('QuantityPerUnit').text();
                            var unitPrice = $(this).find('UnitPrice').text();

                            var html = '<a href="#Product='+ productID +'" title="' + productName + ',' + unitPrice + '">' + productName + '</a>';
                            var categoryElement =  document.getElementById(categoryID);
                            var subList = document.getElementById('Sub_' + categoryID );
                            if(subList == null)
                            {
                                $('<ul id="Sub_' + categoryID + '"></ul>').appendTo(categoryElement);
                                $('<li></li>').html(html).appendTo('#Sub_' + categoryID);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('<li></li>').html(html).appendTo(subList);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('An error occurred while processing Products XML file.');
                    //alert('An error occurred while processing Products XML file.')
                }
            }).done(function(){
                console.log('... done loading content tree.');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu_wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```